# Handle a popup window with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am simply automating the pressing of a start button over and over again as the button only remains on for 20 minutes and 30 seconds. Randomly the program throws an error that causes the button to turn off early. The popup window has no title. I need to press enter (or something) to clear the popup window and then press the start button again. Heres what I have so far and it is not handling the popup error.

How can I press enter to clear the error message and restart the loop?

```
if WinExist("3ple") 
WinActivate
sleep 100

Loop 84

{
Click 1112, 406
Sleep 1232000

if WinExist("")
WinActivate
Send {Enter}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean start button as in windows start button? How about simulating *pressing the windows key* instead?

Comment: No, sorry about the confusion. Its actually a radio button within a window. Not Windows Start button.

Comment: @What seems to be the problem?, can you ask a question.

Comment: It does not handle the popup window. When the window appears I would expect the script to press enter to clear it then restart the loop

Comment: I think `if WinExist("")` will fail to find your popup. Rather determine your pop-ups class and go from there.http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm  Also your if  statement is missing brackets.

Comment: You can do an image search for the dialog - take a screenshot, crop out a distinct area and search using http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

Comment: @Turch That is a very bad idea considering we have known information about. Every window has a handle, you just have to find it.

Comment: Thanks Ill try that! Ive noticed AHK doesnt seem to care too much about brackets.. But its probably better practice.

Comment: @Armin Why? It's a quick solution to a quick problem. Getting a distinct image to search for is trivial, and the problem doesn't imply any performance constraints that would make this unusable.

Comment: @Turch Always prefer a correct solution over a quick and potentially error-prone one.

Comment: I think the bigger problem may be that the Sleep is not interrupted by the following if statement. Can someone confirm that?

Comment: @KyleLuchinski Of course it is not, why would it be.

Comment: @Armin exactly. So that is probably my biggest problem. Can I setup some sort of watchdog to look for the popup at all times?

Comment: @Armin How is it error-prone? If you mean potential false positives, the chance is miniscule if you choose the image right and can happen with the WinGet way as well since you can have multiple windows with the same class.

Comment: @KyleLuchinski use http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm to repeat a function

Comment: @Turch *How is it error-prone?* The ability to notice that distinction is what makes a difference between a good and bad/newbie programer.

Comment: @Armin So you can't back up your statement and turn to begging the question and ad hominem attacks? I can just as easily say "the ability to distinguish when a solution is appropriate is what makes a difference between a good and bad/newbie programmer"

Comment: `ImageSearch` is a bad idea if there is any chance that the popup may move.  I believe this is what Armin is getting at. `WinGet` would be the better solution imo because you could get/use the window's unique ID.  This would more reliable and wouldn't be ruined by a shift in pixels, GUI rework in the program, theme change, etc.

Comment: could you run AHK Window Spy to find the window/object ID's of the windows/buttons in question. Once you have that information, you can start monitoring and sending instruction to THOSE specific windows/objects instead of relying on good faith. Once inside a window that is monitored by AHK Window Spy, hover over the objects and look at the "under the mouse" section.